# AutoSuspension from Chat for "Inappropriate Content"

Tags: support, chat

Someone mind explaining what content was inappropriate, and why the system is automatically banning users now, and can perhaps undo the suspension?

*edit*:

yes i found what content was inappropriate, so i apologize for using the "flagged language".  But for the record, the system autobanning users is not worthy of a support system.  Moderators exist to moderate.  We do not need autobanning bots for that purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no completely automatic ban on chat, a 30 minute suspension is triggered by a successful spam or offensive flag. So you need either multiple 10k+ chat users or one chat moderator to declare the flag valid for the suspension to trigger.

I've checked the post you were suspended for and it was in my opinion harmless, not worth a suspension, so I unsuspended your account.

Comment: Thank you very much.  For what its worth, it should never have been flagged in the first place, because it was intended to be harmless and not worthy of a suspension.

Comment: @Thomas it accrued enough flags from *users* who didn't think it was harmless. It isn't a swearword-list or similar - it responds to excessive flagging.

Comment: @MarcGravell Then I would question the users who flagged specifically:  "Why was this offensive?  How was it considered thus?  Did you even bother to read the context in which the message was stated?"  Further, its the lack of said statements regarding why they believe it offensive (and the inability for the poster of the flagged post to see these statements) which is unfair and unuseful.  Also, for what its worth, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112691/regarding-stackexchange-wide-chat-moderation

Comment: As well, feel free to discuss this with me further on the chat... i'm currently split between about 8 tasks, but respond when pinged on the chat.

Comment: Just to add to what Fabian has said: It's not just local site moderators - when a flag goes up **all** the moderators and 10k users on the StackExchange network see it. There are a lot of those.